# segmentation fault error on defining undefined array and returning from structure in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to return one character array, one integer array from a structure in c.

My data structure is as follows:

```
struct character_frequency
{
        char *characters;
        int *frequency;
};

struct character_frequency collect_character_distribution(char *buffer, long lSize);

struct character_frequency collect_character_distribution(char *buffer, long lSize)
{
        printf("Collecting character distribution...\n");
        char distribution[256][2];
        char *characters;
        int *frequency;
        long for_a;
        int for_b;
        struct character_frequency resultx;

        for (for_a = 0; for_a < lSize; for_a++)
        {
                distribution[(int)buffer[for_a]][0] = (char) buffer[for_a];
                distribution[(int)buffer[for_a]][1]++;
        }

        int cntr = 0;
        for (for_b = 0; for_b < 256; for_b++)
        {
                if (distribution[for_b][1] > 0)
                {
                        characters[cntr] = distribution[for_b][0];
                        frequency[cntr] = distribution[for_b][1];
                }
        }        

        resultx.characters = (char *) characters;
        resultx.frequency = (int *) frequency;

        return resultx;
}
```

And my main function is as follows:

```
int main()
{
        char *buffer;
        long lSize;
        char *characters;
        int *frequency;
        struct Bar result = funct();
        buffer = result.x;
        lSize = result.y;
        struct character_frequency characterFrequency = collect_character_distribution(buffer, lSize);
        characters = characterFrequency.characters;
        frequency = characterFrequency.frequency;
        printf("%s\n", characters);
        //printf("%s\n", (char *) frequency);
        //collect_character_distribution(buffer, lSize);

        return 0;
}
```

I basically want to return multiple values from a struct function. At first, I define them in structures, and after the function steps I want to get the character array and integer array from the structure function.

I have tested `Struct Bar result` function, and it works perfectly. The only problem is on `collect_character_array` structure function.

I get segmentation fault error.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Find a `valgrind` for your OS. It tracks array access and memory allocation, and usually pin-points the problem with dead accuracy.

Comment: `  for (for_a = 0; for_a < for_a; for_a++)`?

Comment: I have edited the question, Beta.

Comment: Is that your real code?

Comment: Yes, it is all my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you declare `char *characters;` and `int *frequency;`, which are pointers. Then in your `for_b` loop you index these arrays. But you have never allocated room for these arrays.

Comment: Paul, I have tried the same methodology in somewhere else, and it worked. Could you give me fully answer?

Comment: Then you were lucky. What will be the size of these arrays? Then use `malloc` to allocate memory for them. Now you can safely index the arrays and return them. Note that your `cntr` varaiable stays `0`.

Comment: Paul, the thing is that, I wanted to define an unknown size of array in this damn C.

Comment: You can't. You can allocate an initial aray, then, when it is too small you can use `realloc` to make it larger. Or you can pre-process the data to find out how large it must be, then allocate it.